# Processing a large dataset

Tags: matlab, dataset

My MATLAB program generates `N=100` trajectories with `T=10^8` time steps in each, i.e.

```
x = randn(10^8,100);
```

Ultimately, I want to process this data set and obtain an average autocorrelation of all trajectories:

```
y = mean(fft(x),2); % output size (10^8, 1)
```

Now since `x` is too big to store, my only viable option is to save it on the hard drive in small chunks of 10^6

```
x1 = randn(10^6, 100);
x2 = randn(10^6, 100);
etc
```

and then obtain `y` by processing each trajectory `n=1:100` individually and accumulating the result:

```
for n=1:100
y = y + fft([x1(:,n); x2(:,n); ...; x100(:,n)]);
end
```

Is there a more elegant way of doing this? I have 100GB of RAM and a pool of 12 workers.

Comment: Have you try to use the function `matfile`? According to mathworks this function `Access and change variables directly in MAT-files, without loading into memory`

Comment: hmmmm you have 100GB of RAM and it's choking on 10^8*100....?

Comment: WAIT! are you really using 100 variables called x1,x2,x3...x100?? That is a **horrible** idea. use cells or 3D matrices!

Comment: Also: "pool of 12 workers" ? Are you trying to use `parfor` ? Do not parfor with big datasets, that makes parfor slower....

Comment: I would suggest waiting for the next release of MATLAB (R2016b), which should support operations on arrays that don't fit in memory (they are called `tall`).

Comment: How should I even store my trajectory to begin with? It's probably not a good idea to have a single .mat file of more than 1GB, so I will be obliged to store a hundred smaller files 1.mat, 2.mat, ... 100.mat, which is a hundred variables, right?

Comment: Also: look into [`memmapfile`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/memmapfile.html). Regarding the size, as long as you save mat files with v7.3 format or later, you can even exceed 2GB per file... BTW, consider using `single` precision to save some memory.

Comment: I don't understand why saving it in small blocks and load them in and accumulate them will save memory, if you want to use your hard drive for temp storage, use swap space, otherwise, try fitting everything in memory, the `fft` function is extremely efficient - also check your JVM setting, you should not be hitting RAM overhead with that data size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easier way would be to generate your data once and then chop it into small pieces you save on disk, or, if possible, create the data on the workers themselves.

```
x = randn(10^8,100);
for ii=1:100
    if ii ~=100
        tmp = x(ii:ii+1e6)
    else
        tmp = x(ii:end); %ii+1e6 would result in end+1
    end
    filename = sprintf('Dataset%i',ii); %create filename
    save(filename,tmp,'-v7.3'); %save file to disk in -v7.3 format
end

y = cell(100,1) %initialise output
parfor ii = 1:100
    filename = sprintf('Dataset%i',ii); %get the filenames back
    load(filename); %load the file
    y{ii} = mean(fft(tmp),2); % I called it tmp when saving, so it's called tmp here
end
```

Now you can accumulate the results from the cell `y` in the desired manner. You can of course play around with the amount of files you create, as less files will be processed faster due to the overhead of [`parfor`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/parfor.html).

Comment: Actually I only needed to set the .mat format to -v7.3 and now a single file is suffcient to store all of my data. I somehow assumed that on a 64bit machine the latest matlab would store its files using the newest format by default, and so I didn't bother to look for such options...